# ERD: Mapping 1:N relationship with attributes to relationship schema

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, erd

I've got an assignment to do for which we have to design a database, draw an ERD and then we have to map the diagram to a relational schema. We were also given a list of steps but I'm not sure which one should I apply for the 1:N relationship with attributes, my best bet would be step 4 but I'm not sure what to do with the attributes of the relationship. Does anyone have any idea? :/

I couldn't post images directly because I don't have enough reputation, so I've uploaded them on snag.gy.

**My ERD looks like this:**
http://i.snag.gy/XiFwf.jpg

**Information about the database:**
http://i.snag.gy/OSBq8.jpg

Is there something wrong with my design or cardinality of the relationship? I tried looking for examples on google how to deal with this kind of relationship but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: a) ' a list of steps' and 'my best bet would be step 4'. What list? What's step 4? This is too much like a homework question, with most of the data left out for many to be really interested in it.

Comment: ER-to-Relational Mapping steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chemist to Project is M:M.
Works resolves this M:M as a 1:N to the Chemist and Project Entities and therefore becomes an entity/table in its own right.
That's where the Hours attribute goes.

Relationships in Chen, per your example,  typically become represented as entities and therefore tables. Since relationships can't have attributes themselves in an RDBMS, we use an entity/table to represent the relationship and so the attributes of the relationship becomes attributes/columns in the resulting entity/table.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but it doesn't make sense because it is the same situation for Chemist to Equipment, but it can't be M:M because equipment can't be assigned to multiple Chemists at the same time.

Comment: It's not the same situation and it does work. A Project can have multiple chemists assigned to it at the same time, right? and A Chemist can be assigned to multiple projects at the same time. You are confusing generic/catalog type equipment with a piece of equipment that has a specific serial number. Multiple chemists can use "an" X-ray machine - but multiple chemists cannot use the same x-ray machine serial number 123.

Comment: Well the instructions says: "A chemist must be assigned to at least one project and one equipment item. A given piece of equipment need not be assigned, and a given project need not be assigned either to a chemist. [Hint partial and full participation]" So If there is already a Chemist working on a project then another Chemist can't be assigned to that particular project.

Comment: Uhm, no. A chemist can be assigned to multiple pieces of equipment OVER TIME. The same piece of equipment can be assigned to different chemists OVER TIME, so the assignment is what resolves this. So the assignment is the resolution of the m:m and contains the date a particular chemist checks out and returns a particular piece of equipment. And I do not see how you get only one chemist per project. It does not say that. Where does it say: "So If there is already a Chemist working on a project then another Chemist can't be assigned to that particular project."

Comment: I suggest you create some sample data and play with that to help you see the nature of the data.

Comment: I get it now, but what's the point of partial and full participation then? Does it change anything when you are creating relationship schema?

Comment: I don't know what is meant by partial and full - wondering that myself. I woodenly more clarification join that. If you get that, I'm happy to help again. good luck.